# Getting 10mb/s speeds on a 1gb network

Tags: windows, networking

I'm at a loss and I've scoured the internet for answers, but none of them seem to work. I have a TP-LINK TL-SG108E 8 Port Gigabit Easy Smart Switch, a desktop, a laptop, and my new Synology 918+ that I just set up, all connected through the switch. The switch is then connected to an Amplifi router, but I'm not transferring anything to the router, I just mention it to give a complete picture. The desktop and laptop are both Windows 10.

My desktop has a 1gb ethernet connection, and it is connected at 1000 full duplex. TCP checksums offload are disabled.
My laptop has a 1gb Intel 82579 internal network adapter, and it's connected at 1000 full duplex. My 918+ has whatever adapter it has, and it is connected at 1000 full. I look on my switch, and all ports are negotiated for 1000 full. MTU's are the default 1500 everywhere I can check them.

When I copy files, the highest speed I ever get is 10 or 11 mb/s. When I'm transferring from my laptop to my desktop I don't mind that much and I've learned to live with it, but I just got this NAS and I'm going to be transferring like 10TB of data to it, and I can't have it going at 10mb/s.

I should be getting close to 100, especially with just these couple devices, and less than 10' of cable between the device and the switch. Doing searches on the internet there's many many people that have this issue, but there are few resolutions.

I'm hoping to get some ideas here.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the ports connected at 1000 and not 100? Why is TCP offload disabled?

Comment: 100% positive. If I could take screenshots and post them I would, I checked every point, and the switch ports themselves, everything is set to 1000/full. TCP offload is disabled because I found on some forums that it messes things up and my issue that other people were having was resolved by doing that. TCP Checksum Offload and Large Send Offload are both disabled.

Comment: I just tested a file copy, and it took almost a full minute to copy a 450mb file.

Comment: Is your disk slow?

Comment: Transferred from my laptop to my desktop, almost 2 minutes for a 1gb file. Checked networking in task manager and it was consistently just under 100Mbps received.

Comment: Shouldn't be, I get the same transfer rates going to/from my new NAS too. I just did a test from the laptop to the NAS, that was a little better, 23MB/s or so. The same file from my desktop to the NAS is a consistent 10MB/s.

Comment: Also, all my cables are pre-made cat6 cables, that are all 15' or less.

Comment: How do you copy the files? Using which command / application? Could you run an [iperf](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#windows) test between laptop and dektop and post the verbose output?

Comment: I've tried copying the files through windows, and I just set a robocopy to run to copy to the NAS last night, and this morning it has copied about 400gb roughly 7 hours.

Comment: How fast can the laptop make a local copy of a 1gb file?  What about the desktop?  Also, have you tried plugging the laptop directly to the desktop rather than via the switch and seeing what speed you get then?  ([According to this article,](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2219416/do-you-need-a-crossover-cable-.html) gigabit ethernet supports connecting two devices directly and you shouldn't need a special cable.)

Comment: ... in theory, it is possible that all the traffic is currently going to the external router and back, which would explain the bottleneck.  I can't quite imagine how that would happen in practice, but if you're desperate enough to take a long shot, try unplugging the Amplifi router during a copy and see if anything odd happens.

Comment: I'll have to try some of that tomorrow. My other friend had me checking the QoS stuff on my switch, but it's all set to unlimited with no bandwidth limiting settings anywhere.

Comment: I connected a cat6 cable to the second nic in my desktop and the second nic in my 918+ andboom, 98MB/s. I'm not sure what's going on with my switch and why it's limiting my transfer speeds though, it's basically set up with default settings.

Comment: Can you please check below,
1. When you are copying any receiving or sending queues on sender or receiver if so you have to tune Ethernet with my changes,
2. Do u see any high I/O or network latency, in that case check disk performance.
3. Any encryption used, if so don't use just for checking and see it improve coping speed
Hope this will help.

Comment: 1. What do you mean tune ethernet with your changes? 2. I don't see any latency. 3. No encryption.

Comment: Does your switch support/have enabled Jumbo Frames/Packets?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? This sounds EXACTLY like what I'm facing.

Answer (score -1):

Do you by chance have HP computers? There are several things that I have seen here that could be your problem. I'll run down a list (I'll try them in most likely to least likely based on what you said):

1) Quite a few HP laptops (and others) have these weird software programs installed from the factory called things like "Network Management" or "Quality of Service" or something like that. Uninstall all of them. They can turn your gigabit wired cards down to ULTRA slow speeds because they think they're being helpful. I've seen it bunches of times.

2) Those little external USB 3.0 things can sometimes not actually be gigabit even though they say gigabit. There are even some crummy computers that are those Intel 825** where they have "built in gigabit" but the CPU is so slow that they can't even pull 1g. I have replaced some computers for exactly that issue. They're a weird "Celeron" or an "APU".

3) Your switch could be broken? Have you tried another switch or a crossover cable or just using the router?

4) Have you tested the capability of the desktop/laptop to copy to itself locally? Can one or both of them not copy data very quickly WITHOUT using the network at all?

5) Some kind of weirdo ipv6 issue. I see this issue periodically as well. Some of the newer routers sloppily implement ipv6 and if you turn it off on your Windows box, things speed up magically.

Comment: 1) No HP Laptops, My desktop is a custom built PC and my laptop is a Dell Latitude. 2) I'm not using USB3, this is all ethernet connections. 3) It's possible, I have another identical one I can swap in with it, I'll try that this weekend. 4) Per the bottom command on my first comment, I connected a cat6 cable to the second nics on the desktop and NAS, and I got my 100+ MB/s transfer rates. 5) I've turned IPV6 off everywhere because it sucks and always seems to contribute to weird issues.